# Absolutely continuous Banach space valued function

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, absolute-continuity

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $F:[a,b] \to X$ be an absolutely continuous function. Is it true that $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere? In particular, for any $f \in L^1([a,b],X)$, is the function 
$$
  F(x) = \int_{[a,x]}f(t) dt  
$$
differentiable almost everywhere and $F'(x) = f(x)$ for almost all $x \in [a,b]$? (where the integral is the Lebesgue integral for Banach spaces)

I would also appreciate any literature where this is covered!

Comment: Not certain what you mean by "the Lebesgue integral for Banach spaces". Are you referring to the [Bochner Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral) for vector measure spaces? You may want to check out *Vector Measures* by Diestel and Uhl.

Comment: @Theo Bendit Yes, I did not know that it had a name. But it is defined the same as the usual Lebesgue integral for simple functions but the scalars are elements in a vector space.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in arbitrary Banach spaces, but for spaces $X$ possessing the "Radon-Nikodym property". A good resource might be the book "Vector measures" by Diestel and Uhl.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, the right replacement for the concept of absolute continuity when dealing with Banach valued functions is the concept of continuous local primitives. It is not that surprising, because the $F$ is called a local primitive of $f$ if
$$
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \int_a^b\left|\frac{1}{h}[F(x+h)-F(x)]-f(x)\right| d x=0
$$

For more context on this you can look at the example on page 172 of the book "The Bochner integral" by Mikusinski (1978), and at theorem Theorem 3.4 of the chapter XIII.